# Reference to "this" component in Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

From what I've read this seems like currently it's not possible: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/4523#issuecomment-596232030

I want to build a tree structure, and want to highlight an active node anywhere on the tree. If I use a store to write/read the currently active node ID, it's pretty easy, just check if the ID matches the component's.

But if I have thousands of nodes, I'm afraid this might get pretty slow as each node checks when current ID changes.

So I thought I could instead store a reference to the currently active node so I could deactivate/activate any node easily. For example:

```js
import { activeNode } from './stores'

let active = false

export function activate() {
  $activeNode.deactivate()
  activeNode.set(this) // <- this is undefined
  active = true
}

export function deactivate() {
  active = false
}
```

I believe something like this would be much faster, as I could call the `activate` method as necessary on any node.

So how can I reference a component instance? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very hackishly access `this` with an `eval` (don't do it), or quite hackishly with complicity of the parent component (`bind:this`)... But you don't need to.

What about exposing just what is needed by the external world?

```html
<script>
    import { activeNode } from './stores.js'

    let active = false

    const api = {
        activate() {
            if ($activeNode) $activeNode.deactivate()
            $activeNode = api // sugar for: activeNode.set(api)
            active = true
        },
        deactivate() {
            active = false
        }
    }
</script>

<div class:active>
    Node
</div>

<style>
    .active {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, though I'm not entirely sure how would I use this `api` for a specific node, could you help with an example? (just a couple days into svelte so far)

Comment: It's your own example updated to not use `this`. You don't actually need `this`, you need to access some methods on `this`. So you can just put those functions you need in an object, and send this object through the pipes, instead of `this`. I've updated the example to make it more clear how you would use it in a component.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me get to where I wanted.